# How to create and use a volume in kubernetes with the Go client API?

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-go-client

What steps are needed to create and mount a local folder as a "persistent volume" in kubernetes, using the Go API?

(I'm using minikube, and trying to do the above, just to have some semi-persistent storage to play around with).

I have managed to define a `Volume` and `VolumeMount` in my `JobSpec`, for a Job that I can run successfully on minikube (see [this code](https://github.com/samuell/k8s-experiments/blob/85d06c/k8sexp.go#L99-L118)), but the volume does not seem to be properly created before referenced by the job in this way.

I started fleshing out some code for a spec of the container, which is commented out in my experiment code, as can be seen in [this code](https://github.com/samuell/k8s-experiments/blob/85d06c/k8sexp.go#L46-L63), but I can't find where to send this volume specification, so that kubernetes will create it. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after I found out how to get error logs from the pods (1), I found the error (Calling `bash`, which didn't exist in the container image (only `sh` existed), and a typo in the mounted path).

Updated working code example available [here](https://github.com/samuell/k8s-experiments/blob/8e7bf4/k8sexp.go).

(1) `kubectl get pods` to get pod id, and then `kubectl logs <podid>` to get the logs.

Comment: Another neat trick is to follow the logs live, like tailing.  

`kubectl logs -f <podid>`